# DeployIfnotexists azure policy failing with error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-policy

I am new to azure policy and i am trying to write a deployifnotexists policy for storage account which will enable point-in-time restore for containers with 300days. It does error while deploying, error saying HttpResourceNotFound and random http request url. I would like to know whether the policy is correct or not and Here is the code i created which i am using:

```
    {
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "storage-pointintime",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy."
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "DeployIfNotExists",
          "Deny",
          "Audit"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
      },
      "retentionInDays": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Retention Days",
          "description": "Set the number of Retention Days."
        },
        "defaultValue": "300"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/restorePolicy",
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/<id>"
          ],
          "existenceCondition": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/restorePolicy.days",
            "equals": "[parameters('retentionInDays')]"
          },
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "incremental",
              "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {
                  "storageAccounts": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "retentionDays": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts'),'/default')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/restorePolicy",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                    "properties": {
                      "retentionInDays": "[parameters('retentionDays')]"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "retentionDays": {
                "value": "[parameters('retentionInDays')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable  point-in-time restore for containers, the type should be `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices`. Azure ARM template does not provide type `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/restorePolicy`.

For example

```
{
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "restorePolicy": {
                    "enabled": "[parameters('isContainerRestoreEnabled')]",
                    "days": "[parameters('containerRestorePeriodDays')]"
                },
                "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": "[parameters('isBlobSoftDeleteEnabled')]",
                    "days": "[parameters('blobSoftDeleteRetentionDays')]"
                },
                "containerDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": "[parameters('isContainerSoftDeleteEnabled')]"
                },
                "changeFeed": {
                    "enabled": "[parameters('changeFeed')]"
                },
                "isVersioningEnabled": "[parameters('isVersioningEnabled')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ]
        }
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-06-01/storageaccounts/blobservices?tabs=json) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-overview).
[image]

Comment: I updated as you suggested but it seems policy is not taking effect. It succeeds but does not update the property which I find is strange

Comment: @mikeknows Could you please check it via activity log?

Comment: @mikeknows Could you please provide your template?

Comment: i am using the template as provided in the description. When i try to update with wrong value then property does not change back to correct

Comment: @mikeknows have you enabled Soft delete blob version and charge feed? Before you can enable point-in-time restore, you need to enable these features.

Comment: let me try that option first, will update you. Thanks.